# how to get directory of current module in Node 7.2.1 - resolve is deprecated?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to resolve the path to a required module:

`var directory = require.resolve('ocs.auth')`

But Webstorm is telling me `Deprecated symbol, consult docs for a better alternative` - but I've checked the Node docs and can't find any reference to it being deprecated.

node version is 7.2.1.

I can expose a directory object `__dirname` from index.js in the module, but I thought resolve should work. Does anyone know why `resolve` was deprecated? and what replaces it?

Answer (score 0):

The official docs don't mention the deprecation. All deprecated methods/ objects are marked as deprecated and also include a marker of the release when the deprecation happened based on the git history. (see this example https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/crypto.md#ecdhsetpublickeypublic_key-encoding). In the past there were some problems with symlinks, but these were solved.

You could even go ahead and turn on some deprecation warnings if you run your script with  `--trace-deprecation` which will warn about all deprecated methods/ objects etc. that your code is using (`require.resolve` won't trigger the deprecation warnings).

My version of WebStorm (2016.3 with the latest patches) doesn't warn about it; maybe some additional code analyzer are enabled and have special settings enabled?